# Chunking dates into mangeable groups w/ python

Tags: python, chunking

I need to create chunks of dates in 30 day chunks and iterate through those. For example, let assume I want to look at 30 day increments for the last 3 years. I need the following:

chunk 1:
end_date:     02-19-2015
start_date:   01-20-2015

chunk 2:
end_date:     01-20-2015
start_date:   12-21-2014

chunk 3:
chunk 4:
....

Then I plug the start_date and end_date into REST API interface.

I was trying to do something like this then use itertools groupby to pull out the last 30 days. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
chunk = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
numdays = 1095
dateList = []
for x in range (0, numdays):
    dateList.append(chunk - datetime.timedelta(days = x))
print dateList
```

Given the solution with dateutil the questions becomes how to easily just pull the first and last element from each chunk. I tried to just loop over the chunks and pull the 0/-1 element but that seems to pull all 30 datapoint out of each chunk instead.

```
 for start in chunks:
  print [chunks[0], chunks[-1]]
```

If I manually assign chunks[0] to a new element I can print them. But that begs the question what is the more efficient way to do this for all chunks

```
chunk0 = chunks[0]
print [chunk0[0], chunk0[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `dateutil`:

```
foo = list(
    dateutil.rrule.rrule(dateutil.rrule.DAILY, 
                         dtstart=datetime.date(2012, 2, 19),
                         until=datetime.date(2015, 2, 19))
)
```

then:

```
In [36]: chunks = [foo[i:i+30] for i in range(0, len(foo), 30)]

In [37]: chunks[0]
Out[37]: 
[datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 20, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 25, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 26, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 27, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 28, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 29, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 6, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 14, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 18, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 19, 0, 0)]

In [38]: chunks[-1]
Out[38]: 
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 6, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 14, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 19, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a shot and it does work, I just need to convert the formatting back into a date string (2015-01-20).  What is the easiest way to pull the start and end_date for each chunk? So that I can just iterate through the entire list of start and end dates?

Comment: For that follow-up, you should add an edit to the question, and also show some code that is your best attempt to do it. Who knows, you might come up with a nice efficient solution yourself ... it's better than for me to just give it away. Teach a man to fish and all that...

Comment: I tried doing something like this; "print [[x[-1] for x in el] for el in chunks]" but i'm getting errors from datetime. 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Since each `el` is itself a whole chunk, you want to get the first and last element of `el` and **not** the first and lest "element" of each and every thing inside of `el`. The things inside of each `el` are themselves going to be instances of `datetime.datetime`, which, as that error is correctly telling you, does not have the ability to slice out specific "items" by any kind of an "index" (which is what `__getitem__` does).

Comment: this works, thanks. for single_chunk in chunks:
        start_date = single_chunk[0]
        end_date = single_chunk[-1]
        print start_date, end_date